# Bash: wrong pipe output when using "sudo sh -c"

Tags: linux, redirect, pipe, sudo

I have a pipe of commands and I use `"sudo sh -c"` for getting sudo permission throughout the whole pipe commands.

The problem that I am facing is that commands like `awk` have different behaviour when `"sudo sh -c"` is used.

In particular,

> sudo wc -c Mybib.bin |sudo awk '{print $1;}'

gives `1509644`

while

> sudo sh -c "wc -c Mybib.bin |awk '{print $1;}'"

gives `1509644 Mybib.bin`

So, in the second case looks like the `awk` command is not invoked at all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, but the double quotes are allowing the `$1` to be replaced before invocation, resulting in `{print ;}`.

```
sudo sh -c "wc -c Mybib.bin |awk '"'{print $1;}'"'"
```

Also...

```
sudo sh -c "wc -c < Mybib.bin"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first solution you gave is not working for me (it gives `1509644 Mybib.bin`) but the second works ok. Is that a property of `awk` that whenever double quotes are used, the variables are replaced before invocation or it has to do with `"sudo sh -c"`?

Comment: Neither. It has to do with the shell that you invoke `sudo` in.

Answer (score 1):

I also found that you can escape the elements in sh -c as well.

For example:
`sudo sh -c "wc -c Mybib.bin |awk '{print \$1;}'"`

At least..that's working for me right now with a problem I ran into that was similar to yours.